# How to display "Add to cart" button even if price is not added in woocommerce in avada theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using avada 4.0.2 theme.
When I add price of a product, `Add to cart` button is displayed everywhere where the product is shown but when there is no price added,
then there is no `Add to cart` button. I want to display "Add to cart" button always even if I don't mention any price in `Regular Price` column.
Actually I want to display a pop up form on clicking a button. I want to display this button on the place of `Add to cart`. for this I am using a  `WooCommerce Email Inquiry & Cart Options LITE` plugin which replaces the `Add to cart` button with `Buy Now` button which on being clicked displays pop up form. 
Now the problem is this button is displayed only when price is added to a product.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to display like I wanted. I could not make `Add to cart` show always rather I wrote `.product-buttons{diaplay:none;}` and `echo` the code of the button in `content-product.php` used in the plugin.[image]